# pkg-config return lib files with prefix and suffix

Tags: opencv, pkg-config

I compiled opencv3 and installed it by defaults.
And then I get libs with pkg-config command as follows:

```
echo `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -llibopencv_dnn.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_ml.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_objdetect.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_shape.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_stitching.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_superres.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_videostab.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_calib3d.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_features2d.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_highgui.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_videoio.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_imgcodecs.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_video.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_photo.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_imgproc.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_flann.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_core.3.3.1.dylib
```

But the returned string include lib prefix and suffix which cannot be used in opencv app compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the .pc file of opencv contains

```
cat /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc                           
# Package Information for pkg-config

prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
includedir_new=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 3.3.1
Libs: -L${exec_prefix}/lib -llibopencv_dnn.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_ml.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_objdetect.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_shape.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_stitching.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_superres.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_videostab.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_calib3d.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_features2d.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_highgui.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_videoio.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_imgcodecs.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_video.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_photo.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_imgproc.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_flann.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_core.3.3.1.dylib
Libs.private: 
Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}
```

So, pkg-config return the contents directly.

Finally, I edited the opencv.pc file and the problem is solved.